# mailboxUsageDetailsRequest returns exception

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

Replacing MSOnline cmdlets with Microsoft.Graph V1.12.0.

Report mailboxUsageDetailsReport = null;
IReportRootGetMailboxUsageDetailRequestBuilder mailboxUsageDetailsRequestBuilder = null;
IReportRootGetMailboxUsageDetailRequest mailboxUsageDetailsRequest = null;

mailboxUsageDetailsRequestBuilder = graphServiceClient.Reports.GetMailboxUsageDetail(period);
mailboxUsageDetailsRequest = mailboxUsageDetailsRequestBuilder.Request();
mailboxUsageDetailsReport = await mailboxUsageDetailsRequest.GetAsync();

The last line throws:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
```

Fiddler shows 302 response with correct file "Location" but body of response contains just a 0,

Work around is

HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, mailboxUsageDetailsRequest.RequestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph .Net client v1.12.0 does not currently support the Reports API in a first class manner. You are sharing the suggested workaround, we thank you for sharing that. The response is a csv file, that's why you see the JsonReaderException.